# Using File Type Array in Extendscript

Tags: extendscript

I am trying to integrate an Array containing a list of image file types that can be used in my Extendscript, this is what I have:

```
DFgroup.DFBtn.onClick = function(){    
     DFdefault = new Folder(DARKinputFolder); //stores the current folder in case of cancel.    
     DFdefault = Folder.selectDialog('****Please Select The Folder Where Your DARK FRAMES Are Located****',DARKinputFolder);
     if ( DFdefault != null ) {
                    DARKinputFolder = DFdefault.fsName.toString()
                       DFgroup.DFlabel.text = DARKinputFolder;

if(DFdefault){DARKinputFolder = DFdefault}; //if cancel is hit, this statement becomes false, and myFolder remains untouched.    
    //if it's true, then the selected folder from the holdFolder is transferred to myfolder.   

var FILE_TYPE, FTlen i;
FILE_TYPE = [".orf", ".tif", ".tiff", ".jpg", ".jpeg"];
FTlen = FILE_TYPE.length;
for (i = 0; i < FTlen; i++){
var SEARCH_MASK = "*" + FILE_TYPE[i];}
var DARKfileList = DARKinputFolder.getFiles(SEARCH_MASK) ;

//if (DARKfileList.length <= 0)
//{
//var FILE_TYPE = ".jpg"; // The type of files that this script works on -- you can change
//var SEARCH_MASK = "*" + FILE_TYPE; // Image file filter to find only those files
//var DARKfileList = DARKinputFolder.getFiles(SEARCH_MASK);
//}


 if (DARKfileList.length == 0)
{
    alert('The DARK FRAME folder you have chosen is either empty or does not contain image files of the correct type.\r\rPlease locate & select the correct image folder.','DARK FRAME folder error');
    DFgroup.DFlabel.text = 'No DARK FRAMES folder has been selected...';
    DFdefault = '';
    DFgroup.DFlabelQ.text = '';
    }
else{                      
                       DFgroup.DFlabelQ.text = '[' + DARKfileList.length + ']';
                       var DFCurrFolder = (new File(DARKinputFolder)).fsName;
                       DFgroup.DFlabel.helpTip = 'Location of files to process:\r' + DFCurrFolder;
                       FolderChecker()
     }}
     } //opens the folder browse UI using you main folder.
```

When a user hits the 'DFBtn' an open folder dialog appears and they can choose a folder that contains images.

This folder path along with the number of images contained within it are retrieved and output as text label on a dialog box.

The problem is that through testing and choosing a folder that does contain an image and that image is of the allowed type, the script goes straight to the 'Alert' message stating that the "folder you have chosen is either empty....." etc..

Now if I alter a small section of the code as:

```
if (DARKfileList.length <= 0)
{
var FILE_TYPE, FTlen, i;
FILE_TYPE = [".orf", ".tif", ".tiff", ".jpg", ".jpeg"];
FTlen = FILE_TYPE.length;
for (i = 0; i < FTlen; i++){
var SEARCH_MASK = "*" + FILE_TYPE[i];}
var DARKfileList = DARKinputFolder.getFiles(SEARCH_MASK) ;}
```

The code now no longer goes straight to the 'Alert' message even if I deliberately choose a folder that is empty.

---

UPDATE

To aid in finding out what is going on I have added an extra line of code:

```
var FILE_TYPE, FTlen i;
FILE_TYPE = [".orf", ".tif", ".tiff", ".jpg", ".jpeg"];
FTlen = FILE_TYPE.length;
for (i = 0; i < FTlen; i++){
var SEARCH_MASK = "*" + FILE_TYPE[i];}
var DARKfileList = DARKinputFolder.getFiles(SEARCH_MASK);
alert (SEARCH_MASK);
```

By just adding this line `alert (SEARCH_MASK);` straight away I had an insight to what is occurring.

Yes the `FILE_TYPE` Array is being iterated through but then the `SEARCH_MASK` is formed using just the last `FILE_TYPE` in the array, so in the case above the `SEARCH_MASK` is always created as:

`*.jpeg`

Therefore it will only be looking for files of that type within the chosen folder.

This is not what I am trying to achieve.

I want to know if the chosen folder contains ANY files of ANY of the types listed in the array.

For instance, the chosen folder could contain all `*.tif` files or even one of each file type.

How can I achieve what I require the code to do?

Regards..,

---

UPDATE 2 ***BOILED DOWN SCRIPT***

Here's a boiled down script as requested:

```
var DARKfileList = '';

var AllowedFileTypes = Array( "orf", "tif", "tiff", "jpg", "jpeg" );



var dlgM = new Window('dialog','***###***###',undefined,{closeButton:false});
dlgM.center();
var DARKinputFolder = new Folder('/C/'); //create a folder to have the dialog start on. 
var DFdefault = new Folder(); //create a holding folder for canceling.

DFg = dlgM.add('panel {text:"DARK FRAMES",preferredSize:[450,15]}');
DFg.margins = [5,10,5,10];
DFg.alignChildren = 'left';
DFgroup = DFg.add('group');
DFgroup.DFBtn = DFgroup.add('button{text:"Select Folder...",preferredSize:[100,25]}');
DFgroup.DFBtn.helpTip = 'Please select your DARK FRAMES folder.';
DFgroup.DFlabel = DFgroup.add( 'statictext', undefined, DARKinputFolder, { truncate:'middle' } );
DFgroup.DFlabel.helpTip = 'Location of files to process';
DFgroup.DFlabel.preferredSize.width = '275';
DFgroup.DFlabel.text = 'No DARK FRAMES folder has been selected...';
DFgroup.DFlabelQ = DFgroup.add( 'statictext', undefined, '');
DFgroup.DFlabelQ.helpTip = 'Number of DARK FRAMES to process';
DFgroup.DFlabelQ.preferredSize.width = '40';
DFgroup.DFlabelQ.text = '';

BTNg = dlgM.add('group {alignment: "center"}');
BTNg.ExitBtn = BTNg.add('button{text:"Exit",preferredSize:[105,25]}');
BTNg.ProcessBtn = BTNg.add('button{text:"Process",preferredSize:[105,25]}');
BTNg.ProcessBtn.enabled = false;

DFgroup.DFBtn.onClick = function(){    
     DFdefault = new Folder(DARKinputFolder); //stores the current folder in case of cancel.    
     DFdefault = Folder.selectDialog('****Please Select The Folder Where Your DARK FRAMES Are Located****',DARKinputFolder);
     if ( DFdefault != null ) {
                    DARKinputFolder = DFdefault.fsName.toString()
                       DFgroup.DFlabel.text = DARKinputFolder;

if(DFdefault){DARKinputFolder = DFdefault}; //if cancel is hit, this statement becomes false, and myFolder remains untouched.    
    //if it's true, then the selected folder from the holdFolder is transferred to myfolder.   

var FTlen, i;
FTlen = AllowedFileTypes.length;
for (i = 0; i < FTlen; i++){
var SEARCH_MASK = "*." + AllowedFileTypes[i]};
var DARKfileList = DARKinputFolder.getFiles(SEARCH_MASK) ;




 if (DARKfileList.length == 0)
{
    alert('The DARK FRAME folder you have chosen is either empty or does not contain image files of the correct type.\r\rPlease locate & select the correct image folder.','DARK FRAME folder error');
    DFgroup.DFlabel.text = 'No DARK FRAMES folder has been selected...';
    DFdefault = '';
    DFgroup.DFlabelQ.text = '';
    }
else{                      
                       DFgroup.DFlabelQ.text = '[' + DARKfileList.length + ']';
                       var DFCurrFolder = (new File(DARKinputFolder)).fsName;
                       DFgroup.DFlabel.helpTip = 'Location of files to process:\r' + DFCurrFolder;
                       FolderChecker()
     }}
     } //opens the folder browse UI using you main folder.

BTNg.ExitBtn.onClick = function(){
dlgM.close();
} 

function FolderChecker(){
   if (DFdefault.exists){
    BTNg.ProcessBtn.enabled = true;
    }
}


BTNg.ProcessBtn.onClick = function(){

// THIS IS WHERE IMAGE PROCESSING STARTS -- REMOVED THIS HUGE SECTION FOR BREVITY

}


dlgM.show();
```

---

UPDATE 3  ***Final Issue***

As per my comment about the need to check for illegal file types etc, here's what I have so far:

```
if (DARKfileList.length == 0)
{
    alert('empty folder!','DARK FRAME folder error');
    DFgroup.DFlabel.text = 'No DARK FRAMES folder has been selected...';
    DFdefault = '';
    DFgroup.DFlabelQ.text = '';
    }

else if (DARKfileList.length > 1)
{
    alert('too many file types!','DARK FRAME folder error');
    DFgroup.DFlabel.text = 'No DARK FRAMES folder has been selected...';
    DFdefault = '';
    DFgroup.DFlabelQ.text = '';
    }

else{                      
                       DFgroup.DFlabelQ.text = '[' + DARKfileList.length + ']';
                       var DFCurrFolder = (new File(DARKinputFolder)).fsName;
                       DFgroup.DFlabel.helpTip = 'Location of files to process:\r' + DFCurrFolder;
                       FolderChecker()
     }
```

Now this works perfectly if the chosen folder contains only one file & that file is not in the `FILE_TYPE` array as `DARKfileList.length` returns zero. **As Required**

Similarly if the folder contains more than one of any file no matter what type the check fails. **As Required**

However, if a chosen folder contains one allowed `FILE_TYPE` & one file type that is not in the `FILE_TYPE` array the check fails. **Needs Sorting Out**

I need something along the lines of:

```
if (DARKfileList != FILE_LIST)
{
        alert('Illegal file type!);
        DFgroup.DFlabel.text = 'No DARK FRAMES folder has been selected...';
        DFdefault = '';
        DFgroup.DFlabelQ.text = '';
}
```

Comment: can you boil your code down to something we could test?

Comment: @fabiantheblind added as update 2, regards..,

Comment: Forgot to add that the function that checks the folder for files of type as listed in the AllowedFileTypes variable need to show an alert if the indexed folder contains a mix of these types. The function should only continue to processing if the indexed folder contains only one type from the allowed types list. Hope that make it more clear as to the use

Comment: As per UPDATE 3 above, regards..,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that each iteration you overriding the resulting search mask.

You need to merge all the resulting into one array, and then to check if your array is empty:

```
var DARKfileList = [], FILE_TYPE, FTlen, i, SEARCH_MASK;
FILE_TYPE = ["orf", "tif", "tiff", "jpg", "jpeg"];
FTlen = FILE_TYPE.length;
for (i = 0; i < FTlen; i++) {
    SEARCH_MASK = "*." + FILE_TYPE[i];
    DARKfileList = DARKfileList.concat(DARKinputFolder.getFiles(SEARCH_MASK));
}
alert('found: ' + DARKfileList.length + ' files');
```

Alternative: `getFiles` can get regex as parameter, so if you familiar with regex you can simply use the following regex:

```
/.+\.(?:jpe?g|tiff?|orf)$/i
```

Regex explanation: match in the filename any character, then dot character, and then one of the extension option and then the `i` flag used to ignore case sensitive. **In your example you get only files that the extension is in lowercase**.

To add another extensions to the regex, just add pipe(`|`) after `orf` and then your extension. ex: to add `pdf` extension:

```
/.+\.(?:jpe?g|tiff?|orf|pdf)$/i
```

Usage of regex in your code:

```
DARKfileList = DARKinputFolder.getFiles(/.+\.(?:jpe?g|tiff?|orf|pdf)$/i);
```

You can also use array to store all of your extensions and use it like:

```
var regex = new RegExp('.+\.(?:' + FILE_TYPE.join('|')+ ')$','i');
DARKfileList = DARKinputFolder.getFiles(regex);
```

Comment: Cheers, I'm away from my PC right now but I'll give your suggestions a try and report back

Comment: As per UPDATE 3 above, regards..,